# Wordpress: post edit action hook

Tags: wordpress

What is post edit action hook that i can put plugin translation path for custom type post.php?

```
function wp_professionals_load_plugin_textdomain()
{
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'wp-professionals', FALSE, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
add_action( '????', 'wp_professionals_load_plugin_textdomain' );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a hook that fires when a post is created or updated, you should use [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). It fires just after the post is successfully saved in the database.

```
function wp_professionals_load_plugin_textdomain($post_id)
{
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'wp-professionals', FALSE, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wp_professionals_load_plugin_textdomain' );
```

Note that [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) also passes `$post_id` to your function in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is edit_post hook right?

```
do_action( 'edit_post', int $post_ID, WP_Post $post )
```

Please try it